# Why is my variable resetting to zero in react-native and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm still learning Redux. My goal is creating a progress bar in react-native and redux that I want to update every second for play, pause, rewind and fast-forward(rewind/fast-forward at 2x, 6x, and 30x speed). I'm starting with play and rewind2x, since I think I can figure out the others from there.

I have a container that passes down boolean props that tell me what key is being pressed(play or rewind for now) and I'm getting data that gives the current time, program start time and program end time. On mount, the progress bar is in play mode, with current time - program start time giving me the starting point for my progress bar. And program end time - program start time for the program length. I initially get that data fine.

Ex. (30 minute point in 1 hour long show) 
currentProgress = 1800
programLength = 3600

But it resets to zero after my setInterval, I believe. I'm not sure why? Am I allowed to update with redux in setInterval? I've read somewhere that it's not the best thing to do, but then how do I update it every second? Should I go about this completely different?

Hopefully that's enough information, let me know if you need more.

**Actions**

```
//SETS PROGRAM LENGTH AND CURRENT PROGRESS
import {
    GET_PROGRAM_LENGTH,
    GET_CURRENT_PROGRESS
} from '../types/progressbar';

export const getProgramLength = (programLength) => ({
    type: GET_PROGRAM_LENGTH,
    programLength
});

export const getCurrentProgress = (currentProgress) => ({
    type: GET_CURRENT_PROGRESS,
    currentProgress
 });
```

**Reducers**

```
import {
    GET_PROGRAM_LENGTH,
    GET_CURRENT_PROGRESS
} from '../types/progressbar';

const initialState = {
    programLength:  0,
    currentProgress: 0
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_PROGRAM_LENGTH:
            return{
                ...state,
                programLength: action.programLength
            };
        case GET_CURRENT_PROGRESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                currentProgress: action.currentProgress
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

***Some* of the Component**
I'm basically just rendering (currentProgress/ProgramLength * widthOfProgressBar) in a  tag

```
export default class ProgressBar extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        bounceValue: new Animated.Value(200),
    }

    this.timerInterval = null;
    this.closeProgressBar = this.closeProgressBar.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { programLength, currentProgress, onGetProgramLength, onGetCurrentProgress } = this.props;
    const { isPlaying } = this.props.currentProgressState;

    onGetProgramLength(moment(this.props.channelInfo.programs[0].end).diff(this.props.channelInfo.programs[0].start) / 1000);
    onGetCurrentProgress(moment(this.props.currentTime).diff(this.props.channelInfo.programs[0].start) / 1000)

    this.timerInterval = setInterval(()=>{
        console.log("Is Playing", isPlaying);
        console.log("current progress", currentProgress);
        let newCurrentProgress = currentProgress + 1;
        onGetCurrentProgress(newCurrentProgress);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Use `this.props.currentProgress` in the `setInterval` rather than destructuring it from props on the first line of `componentDidMount`. That way it'll use the most up-to-date value each time the interval callback runs.

Comment: That's amazing, I spent two days trying to figure this out. Do you know if this is only a problem in setInterval? or is it an issue with all redux variables in general? Also, how do I choose your comment as an answer?

Comment: I'll post an answer with additional details regarding your followup question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.props.currentProgress` in the `setInterval` rather than destructuring it from props on the first line of `componentDidMount`. That way, the most up-to-date value is used each time the interval callback runs.

In general, functions that use variables from outside their scope (in this case, you're assigning the value of `this.props.currentProgress` to a variable called `currentProgress`) will continue to use the value of that variable when they rerun. You are not reassigning the `currentProgress` variable with the updated value of `this.props.currentProgress`.

Another solution to your problem is destructuring `currentProgress` from props *within* the `setInterval` callback.